# Serial downvoting

Tags: discussion

Why are some people allowed to serial downvote? I have had the same person downvote me multiple times This is very discouraging. It seems like they should be reprimanded?

Comment: Did the downvoters tell you they were the ones clicking the down arrow? If not how would you know?

Comment: @MichaelKaras I had several exchanges on a question with a member and proved him wrong on an answer. He then told me what he thought of me. Then, I noticed 6 downvotes within 30 minutes on various questions.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I had the same thing happen the day before yesterday with same member.

Comment: @MichaelKaras He’s the same person that is using the F*** word too. (See my preceding question.)

Comment: See [this Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) for details on how SE deals with serial voting

Answer (score 1):

Serial downvoting is automatically reverted by an automated batch job when it exceeds the criteria set by SE. Looking over the stats on the backend, I can see that this has occurred in your case, at least in aggregate (we do not see individual votes).

Since we cannot review individual votes, mods do not take action based on user voting and we rely on the automated jobs to handle any problematic behavior. If you see comments or Q&A from users that violate our [code of conduct](https://diy.stackexchange.com/conduct) then please flag that specific content rather than publicly posting here so that we may handle it on a case by case basis.

Comment: So you don’t think it should be discussed?  ...just flag it?

Comment: @LeeSam for a code of conduct violation, there shouldn't be anything to discuss, we can handle those flags. But that needs to be on some content, rather than voting behavior.

Comment: Who is “we”?????

Comment: @LeeSam site moderators, the ones that handle the flags.